# Return Path tracking for Single Sends in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, return-path-platform

I know that Journey Builder sends are not tracked automatically in Return Path, just as triggered sends. We now solve this with an automation that periodically sends the mail to the Return Path inboxes. For example our welcome email.

But what about the new Single Send feature in Journey Builder. We want to start using this instead of sending mails from Email Studio.

What will be the best solution to include the Return Path seed list to these sends (if not done automatically)

Comment: I believe there is no workaround at this moment, the only way to go is what you're already doing: sending to the seedlist using an email activity on Automation Studio. We've talked to our account manager and asked for this feature as well.

Comment: @RachidMamai, Thanks for your fast respond. Clear!